# Erro - Query: A subconsulta retornou mais de 1 valor

Tags: sql, sql-server, query

Sou novo em SQL e estou com o seguinte erro na minha consulta: "A subconsulta retornou mais de 1 valor. Isso não é permitido quando a subconsulta segue um =, !=, <, <= , >, >= ou quando ela é usada como uma expressão".

A query é esta:

```
SELECT distinct 
    (PP.ProjDesc),
    U1.UsuRazaoSocial,
    C.CompDesc QtdeCNPJs,
    U1.UsuUF,
    T.TarID,
    U.UsuNome 'Responsável',
    CONVERT(DATE, PP.DataInicio, 103) Data_Início,
    CONVERT(DATE, PP.DataPrevLiberacao,103) Data_Fim,
    DATEDIFF(DAY,PP.DataInicio ,GETDATE()) Dias_Decorridos,
    SLA_Projeto = 
        CASE WHEN PP.DataPrevLiberacao >= GETDATE() THEN 
            'Dentro do Prazo' 
        ELSE 
            'FORA do Prazo' 
        END,
    (SELECT 
         COUNT(T.TarID) 
     FROM Projetos P
     INNER JOIN Tarefa T ON P.ProjID = T.ProjID
     WHERE P.ProjID = PP.ProjID) QtdeTarefas,
    (SELECT 
         COUNT(T.TarID) 
     FROM Projetos P
     INNER JOIN Tarefa T ON P.ProjID = T.ProjID
     WHERE T.TarStatus = 9
     AND P.ProjID = PP.ProjID) QtdeConcluidas,
    (SELECT 
          Faturado = 
              CASE T1.TarEstagioID WHEN 112 THEN 
                  'SIM' 
              ELSE 
                  'NÃO' 
              END
      FROM Projetos P
      INNER JOIN Tarefa T1 ON P.ProjID = T1.ProjID
      WHERE T1.TarStatus = 9
      AND T1.TarTitulo = 'Treinamento Realizado - Emitir Boleto Setup'
      AND P.ProjID = PP.ProjID
      AND T1.TarTipID = 674) Faturado,
     (SELECT 
          COUNT(T.TarID) 
      FROM Projetos P
      INNER JOIN Tarefa T ON P.ProjID = T.ProjID
      WHERE T.TarStatus = 1
      AND P.ProjID = PP.ProjID) QtdeAtendimento,
     (SELECT 
          COUNT(T.TarID) 
      FROM Projetos P
      INNER JOIN Tarefa T ON P.ProjID = T.ProjID
      WHERE T.TarStatus NOT IN (1,9)
      AND P.ProjID = PP.ProjID) QtdePendentes,
     (SELECT 
          COUNT(T.TarID) 
      FROM Projetos P
      INNER JOIN Tarefa T ON P.ProjID = T.ProjID
      WHERE T.TarStatus = 5
      AND T.TarEstagioID IN (160)
      AND P.ProjID = PP.ProjID) QtdePendentesCliente,
     (SELECT 
          COUNT(T.TarID) 
      FROM Projetos P
      INNER JOIN Tarefa T ON P.ProjID = T.ProjID
      WHERE T.TarStatus = 0
      AND T.TarEstagioID IN (8)
      AND P.ProjID = PP.ProjID) QtdePendentesOperadora,
     (SELECT 
          COUNT(T.TarID) 
      FROM Projetos P
      INNER JOIN Tarefa T ON P.ProjID = T.ProjID
      WHERE T.TarStatus = 0
      AND T.TarEstagioID IN (114)
      AND P.ProjID = PP.ProjID) QtdePendentesBoavista
  FROM PROJETOS PP
  INNER JOIN Tarefa T ON PP.ProjID = T.ProjID
  INNER JOIN Usuario U ON T.UsuIDResponsavel = U.UsuID
  INNER JOIN Usuario U1 ON T.UsuIDCliente = U1.UsuID
  LEFT JOIN Complemento C ON C.UsuID = T.UsuIDCliente and C.CompID = 1
  WHERE T.Macprocid = 33
  AND T.TarTipID = 866
```

Comment: o problema parece estar nesse subselect `(SELECT Faturado = CASE T1.TarEstagioID WHEN 112 THEN 'SIM' ELSE 'NÃO' END
FROM Projetos P
INNER JOIN Tarefa T1 ON P.ProjID = T1.ProjID
WHERE T1.TarStatus = 9
AND T1.TarTitulo = 'Treinamento Realizado - Emitir Boleto Setup'
AND P.ProjID = PP.ProjID
AND T1.TarTipID = 674) Faturado,` que pode retornar mais de uma linha

Comment: se eu executar somente essa subconsulta, ela gera normalmente

Comment: Aliás, desculpas, ele realmente ocorre um erro quando executo essa subconsulta. o Erro é: Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 6
O identificador de várias partes "PP.ProjID" não pôde ser associado.

Comment: não é a consulta que está errada, e vc não consegue executar somente ela porque ela depende de valores das consultas superiores. O problema é que ela pode retornar mais de uma linha, o que não pode acontecer em subconsultas. tente colocar assim:

Comment: `(SELECT TOP 1 Faturado = CASE T1.TarEstagioID WHEN 112 THEN 'SIM' ELSE 'NÃO' END FROM Projetos P INNER JOIN Tarefa T1 ON P.ProjID = T1.ProjID WHERE T1.TarStatus = 9 AND T1.TarTitulo = 'Treinamento Realizado - Emitir Boleto Setup' AND P.ProjID = PP.ProjID AND T1.TarTipID = 674) Faturado,`

Comment: @RenanBessa: Qual é o resultado que a consulta deve retornar? // Percebo que há projeto e que um projeto pode ser composto de uma ou mais tarefas. E que é necessário obter informações sintéticas sobre cada projeto. Mas há uma mistura de relatório sintético (acumuladores de projeto, por exemplo), com analítico (informações individuais de cada tarefa). // Qual é a regra para calcular o valor da coluna Faturado? A informação deve ser gerada por projeto ou por projeto/tarefa?

Comment: Alguma resposta ajudou a resolver o problema e pode sanar dúvidas similares de outros usuários? Caso positivo não esqueça de marcar a resposta como aceita. Pra fazer isso é só clicar no ✓ do lado esquerdo da mesma (abaixo do indicador de up e down votes).

Answer (score 1):

O problema é que a sua `subquery` para retornar o campo `faturado` está retornando mais de um valor. Você pode usar um `DISTINCT` caso garanta que o resultado da `query` está correto:

```
...

(SELECT DISTINCT CASE T1.TarEstagioID WHEN 112 THEN 
              'SIM' 
          ELSE 
              'NÃO' 
          END
  FROM Projetos P
  INNER JOIN Tarefa T1 ON P.ProjID = T1.ProjID
  WHERE T1.TarStatus = 9
  AND T1.TarTitulo = 'Treinamento Realizado - Emitir Boleto Setup'
  AND P.ProjID = PP.ProjID
  AND T1.TarTipID = 674) AS Faturado

...
```